# Update an image, but break the other images php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with my edit page. There is definitely something I'm missing here.

I can add and view my featured products perfectly, but as soon as I go to edit one of the images to another image all other 5 images break, and then when I go to my view, they break there as well.

Here is what it looks like on the edit page
[image]

[image]

Here is what it looks like on the view page

[image]

All I want to do is update each image individually without it affecting my other images.

Here is my code for my edit page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
 
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
?>

 
<?php 

require_once 'connect.php';

require_once 'editfeaturedheader.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            
            $image1 = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['image1']['name']);
            $image2 = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['image2']['name']);
            $image3 = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['image3']['name']);
            $image4 = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['image4']['name']);
            $image5 = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['image5']['name']);
            $image6 = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['image6']['name']);
            
        
        $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
        $sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE featuredproducts SET image1 = ?, image2 = ?, image3 = ?, image4 = ?, image5 = ?, image6 = ? WHERE featuredproduct_id = ?");
        $sql->bind_param("ssssssi", $image1, $image2, $image3, $image4, $image5, $image6, $id);
        if($sql->execute()) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Successfully updated product</div>";
            }else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error: There was an error while updating product info</div>";
                }
        }

        $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
        $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM featuredproducts WHERE featuredproduct_id = ?");
        $sql->bind_param('i', $id);
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();

        if($result->num_rows < 1){
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
        }
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    ?>
    
    
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="box">
            <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Modify Featured Products</h3><br>
            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['featuredproduct_id']; ?>" name="featuredproductid">
                <label for="name">Image 1</label><br><br>
                <span><?php echo '<img src="Images/'. $row['image1'], '" />'?></span><br><br>
                <input type="file"  name="image1" id="image1" value="<?php echo $row['image1']; ?>"  class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="name">Image 2</label><br><br>
                <span><?php echo '<img src="Images/'. $row['image2'], '" />'?></span><br><br>
                <input type="file"  name="image2" id="image2" value="<?php echo $row['image2']; ?>"  class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="name">Image 3</label><br><br>
                <span><?php echo '<img src="Images/'. $row['image3'], '" />'?></span><br><br>
                <input type="file"  name="image3" id="image3" value="<?php echo $row['image3']; ?>"  class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="name">Image 4</label><br><br>
                <span><?php echo '<img src="Images/'. $row['image4'], '" />'?></span><br><br>
                <input type="file"  name="image4" id="image4" value="<?php echo $row['image4']; ?>"  class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="name">Image 5</label><br><br>
                <span><?php echo '<img src="Images/'. $row['image5'], '" />'?></span><br><br>
                <input type="file"  name="image5" id="image5" value="<?php echo $row['image5']; ?>"  class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="name">Image 6</label><br><br>
                <span><?php echo '<img src="Images/'. $row['image6'], '" />'?></span><br><br>
                <input type="file"  name="image6" id="image6" value="<?php echo $row['image6']; ?>"  class="form-control"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success button2" value="Update">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code for the view page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
 
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
?>
 
<?php 

require_once 'connect.php';

require_once 'viewfeaturedheader.php';

require_once 'previewheader.php';

echo "<div class='container'>";

if( isset($_POST['delete'])){
    
    if($sql = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM featuredproducts WHERE featuredproduct_id = ?"))
            {
            $sql->bind_param("i", $_POST['featuredproductid']);
            $sql->execute();
            $sql->close();
            }
            else{
                echo ("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error: There was an error while deleting product</div>");   
            }
            echo ("<div class='alert alert-success'>Successfully deleted product</div>");

}


$sql    = "SELECT * FROM featuredproducts";
$result = $con->query($sql); 

if( $result->num_rows > 0)

{ 
?>
    
<h2>List of all Featured Products</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">Image 1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">Delete</td>
            <td>EDIT</td>
        </tr>
        
        
<?php
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";  //added
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='". $row['featuredproduct_id']."' name='featuredproductid' />"; //added
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'<img src="Images/', $row['image1'], '" />' . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger' /></td>";  
        echo "<td><a href='editfeatured.php?id=".$row['featuredproduct_id']."' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'<img src="Images/', $row['image2'], '" />' . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger' /></td>";  
        echo "<td><a href='editfeatured.php?id=".$row['featuredproduct_id']."' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'<img src="Images/', $row['image3'], '" />' . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger' /></td>";  
        echo "<td><a href='editfeatured.php?id=".$row['featuredproduct_id']."' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'<img src="Images/', $row['image4'], '" />' . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger' /></td>";  
        echo "<td><a href='editfeatured.php?id=".$row['featuredproduct_id']."' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'<img src="Images/', $row['image5'], '" />' . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger' /></td>";  
        echo "<td><a href='editfeatured.php?id=".$row['featuredproduct_id']."' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'<img src="Images/', $row['image6'], '" />' . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger' /></td>";  
        echo "<td><a href='editfeatured.php?id=".$row['featuredproduct_id']."' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>"; //added 
    }
?>
    </table>

<?php 
}
else
{
    echo "<br><br>No Record Found";
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have the same issue on my products page where the product image and a pdf link do the same thing, I have to update both, if I update one or the other it breaks one or the other. Its been driving me nuts.

Comment: You need a separate form for each row of the table

Comment: Either that or you should check whether anything has been submitted for each image variable before adding it to your update SQL

Comment: @ADyson, thank you so much for getting back to me. I tried using different form but kept getting errors, I did solve the problem though. I made 1 column in the database called images, instead of using 6 separate ones. I can now add as many images to that 1 column, display them individually and update individually without it affecting anything.

Comment: Not sure how having only one column is really any help? And, adding multiple items to the same column goes against relational database principles, and could cause you other issues later on. This isn't a good solution. There's no reason you can't keep the current structure, but just change it so that you build the SQL dynamically based on which values have been submitted. Or, the multiple-form approach, what exactly did you try? What errors did you get? It's impossible to know what went wrong from such a vague description.

Comment: Totally understand what you mean about my solution not being the best practice, In the HTML part for the form, I did what you suggested in terms of creating multiple forms, i created a form for each image, by separating them, SQL would give me an error on each form stating that the other image index not found? It seems like the php was not correlating to the separate forms.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to make it so the SQL would only try to find one image at a time, just the submitted one. You'd have to give the all the file inputs the same "name" (since they'd be distinct within each form) so that PHP can look for the same name, no matter which form was submitted. Your featuredproducts table is denormalised too btw - you should have a separate featuredproductimages table for the images (then you're not fixed at 6 per product and can be flexible about changes, and also it makes the saving process easier, as each form would just have a hidden ID field identifying the row).

Comment: ok cool beans, thank you so much. I am going to give that a go, just have some other things to finish up on the site and I'll go back to this and follow your suggestions and let you know. :)